# Modification of merging function in sklearn AgglomerativeClustering

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to implement [Chakrabarti](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.91.2915&rep=rep1&type=pdf) algorithms for smooth clustering over time. For agglomerative clustering, a choice for next clusters to be merged depends on two components:

- similarity between subclusters at current time stamp
- historical cost related to the previous time stamp.

The latter has several variations. For example, one includes merge distance (not only that): if we would merge two subclusters **S1** and **S2**, what would be the average distance (in terms of edges) between all leaves in **S1** and **S2**.

I consider to modify [sklearn AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) for these algorithms and I have a couple of questions:

1. What lines in the  library code implement a choice of clusters to be merged at the current step?
2. Is it possible to extract a distance between a leaf and a root of a subcluster at each merging step? I noticed there is an attribute 'children_' in [AgglomerativeClustering](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html) which might be used for creating the resulting tree and finding distances between any nodes. How to extract such an information for every merging step?

Comment: Please do not cross-post duplicates: https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/25776/924